# How to check if a symbol is a macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

In common lisp, I would like to be able to find out wether or not a symbol is a macro or not. Is there a predicate such as `(macrop)` which will allow me to detect if a name/symbol is a macro?

Comment: Nitpick: a symbol _is_ never a macro.  It may _name_ a macro.

Comment: @Svante: 'may' opens up an interesting can of worms: local&lexical macros where symbols are not direct names and local&lexical symbol macros, where symbols are kind macros...

Comment: @RainerJoswig: _may_be ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `macro-function` returns non-NIL, then it is a macro.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defmacro foo (bar) bar)
FOO

CL-USER 2 > (macro-function 'foo)
#<anonymous interpreted function 40600108FC>
```

Note that this works for typical global macros. There are also local&lexical macros, symbol macros, ...

Comment: I found this whilst trying to determine whether or not a symbol names a symbol macro. The marked answer doesn't work.

The situtation is this:

I am passed a symbol in a function. If it's a symbol macro I get the value with `eval`; if it's not, I get the value with `symbol-value`. To do that without error though, I need to know if it's a symbol-macro.

Is there an equivalent to `macro-function` that works on symbol macros?

Comment: @CL-USER : see the non-standard function `VARIABLE-INFORMATION`.